# sqlite3 unrecognized token error for ( md5 or sha1)

Tags: python, sqlite, md5, sha

how to create a table with sha1 or md5 as table name in sqlite3 using python, i am getting Exception OperationalError saying unrecognized token, is there any alternate method

Comment: Please post the full traceback and the appropriate part(s) of your code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using value of function like md5.hexdigest() as a table name. If so, then you need to take into account fact that **hash value may start from a digit**. SQLite doesn't allow you to start table name from a digit. The simplest solution would be to add some kind of prefix, like:

```
>>> table_name = "table%s" % hashlib.sha1('blurp').hexdigest()
>>> print(table_name)
table5187399948bdcff4fa10220cd8509257567c6b5a
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('create table md5 (mycol)') # if you're being very literal
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x35b7dc0>
>>> import hashlib
>>> tbl_name = hashlib.sha1('test').hexdigest()
>>> conn.execute('create table {} (mycol)'.format(tbl_name)) # otherwise
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x35b7dc0>
```

Caveat: do not use string interpolation in any settings where you're getting user-input as you will be at risk for SQL-injection attacks.